# I cannot set drawable property from drawable located in drawable-hdpi in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to set an Alert Dialog with different background.

I created an inset drawable to be used in a style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:drawable="@drawable/frame.9"
   android:insetTop="14dp"
   android:insetLeft="14dp" />
```

my drawable is located in @drawable-hdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi etc

but I get I cannot resolve symbol @drawable/frame.9

What I am missing here? 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I needed to type the filename as @drawable/frame without the .9 thank you